# Running the python scripts as both standlone scripts and also as nosetests

Tags: testing, scripting, config, combinations, nose

I have python scripts which are run with a config file on CLI. All the contents of the test script are inside class "ABC".

In the **init** of class ABC, I pass config file which gets used in the script.

So when I run my python script standalone I would say "python script_one.py -c config.cfg"

Now the issue is that I need to run all the python tests in the directory using nosetests. The libraries of nose tests do not like the fact that I am passing "config" in the **init**() of class ABC.

I need a way of running the python as mentioned above with config and also as nosetests.

I switched to ConfigParser module in Python which parses config files and I do not have to pass them to the **init**()

```
class TestMe(object):
    def __init__(self):
        config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
        config.read(file)
```

config file is being referenced in **main**():

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    #config = c.parse_config()
    #test = TestMe(config)
    file = "configs/test_config.yaml"
    print "inside main..."
    config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
    config.read(file)
```

If **config=c.parse_config()** and **test=TestMe(config)** had been used, then I would had to pass my config file (xyz.cfg) as "script_1.py -c xyz.cfg) - is there a way to leverage this in nose tests? I ask this because nose tests wont let me pass "config" to **init**() of the class TestMe.

The config.read(file) leads to an error when I do "nosetests script_1.py"

```
E
======================================================================
ERROR: Failure: TypeError ('type' object is not iterable)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 519, in makeTest
    return self._makeTest(obj, parent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/loader.py", line 578, in _makeTest
    return MethodTestCase(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose/case.py", line 345, in __init__
    self.inst = self.cls()
  File "/home/..../script_1.py", line 30, in __init__
    config.read(file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 300, in read
    for filename in filenames:
TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Is there a way I can run my scripts standalone with config and also with nosetests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nose-testconfig solves it all! very handy!